# Why I am getting different results when I run this code in my Python console?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a simple range code example:

```
range(5, 10)
```

Output should be: `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, according to the website I'm working on and seen videos on. When I run this code in my Python console I get these result:

```
>>> range (5,10)
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not what happens in any python version. Can you actually post the code used for the second example?

Comment: I wasn't aware that this tutorial was python 2 which i don't use its python 3. I did the code suggested below print(list(range(5,10) and got the results I was looking for. This is a mistake well learned... thanks for the help all

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get the output you want, in Python 2 and Python 3:

#### Python 2

```
>>> range(5,10)
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

#### Python 3

```
>>> list(range(5,10))
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The tutorial you're following is probably for Python 2 but your question is tagged Python 3, are you sure this is the right tutorial for you?